# Silverlight toolkit Accordion bug?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

This is my very simple Accordion XAML :-

```
<toolkit:Accordion Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="OneOrMore" MinHeight="500">
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="Welcome" Margin="10,0"  IsSelected="True" />
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="Family news" Margin="10,0" />
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="Random photos" Margin="10,0" />
    <toolkit:AccordionItem Header="News articles" Margin="10,0" />
</toolkit:Accordion>
```

If I click few times on the accordion item very fast I get this exception :-

```
AccessViolationException
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Install latest Toolkit..

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528#DownloadId=117046

Then create new project. Add Accordion control on it... try to repit the error..

PS: I don't think this is an accordion fault... Accordion work just fine...

Comment: @ai :- I think it is bug only because if i remove `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` from the markup it works just fine.

Comment: do you have some panels or controls that you made by your self in this app?

Comment: No custom panels. It's all provided by framework and toolkit itself.